# ASP.NET MasterPage, doesn't display my <%=CodeBehindVar %>

Tags: c#, master-pages, webforms

Here is an example of what I want to do:

Content side (Structure.master):

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Structure.master.cs" Inherits="Structure" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Bienvenue sur</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" content="" />
    <link runat="server" href="App_Themes/Global/Metro.css?v=22" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link runat="server" href="App_Themes/Global/Site.css?v=<%=Version %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link runat="server" href="App_Themes/Global/Structure.css?v=22" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And codebehind (Structure.master.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using BaseInstanceEntity = Library.Common.Entities.BaseEntities.BaseInstanceEntity;
using BaseInstanceManager = Library.Manager.BaseInstanceManager;

public partial class Structure : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string Version { get; set;}

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Version = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Version"].Replace(".", "");
```

As shown, I want to display the `Version` var into the header, as a cache control. When I execute the code above, the result on the line is:

```
<link href="../App_Themes/Global/Site.css?v=&lt;%=Version %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

It's like the code isn't interpreted. I couldn't manage to find explanation. Why is this happening?

Comment: have u tried with runat="server" ?

Comment: There is "runat=server" on the link tags, also on the head tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I got to this question late but when I need to create CSS links dynamically I just generate the entire tag on code behind and the just plant it on mark-up like this:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string link;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ver = "1.0.0";
        link = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\"  href=\"../App_Themes/Global/Site.css?v=" + ver + "\"/>";
    }
}
```

then mark up

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<%= link %>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Hopefully this will help someone else who comes to this page!

Comment: I've finally used a RadStyleSheetManager (http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/stylesheetmanager.html) (we own Telerik), it is much easier.

Thank's you for your answer, but i can't embed "<%= link %>" in the header tag.

I CAN'T understand WHY this 'top class' technology selled by microsoft is so crappy when you got to specific implementation. WHat a hell !!!
Never ever i'll take again a job in these things.

Comment: you dont need to embed anything, the tag `<%= link %>` will be processed before the page is rendered by the browser and the tag will transform into whatever text it equals to. Even if you use the tag way before the HTML tag, the text will print in the page before anything else happens because its processed at the server side. Post your code if you are still working on this and I will try to help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it should be like this:

```
<link runat="server" 
      href='<%# string.Format("{0}?v={1}", Page.ResolveUrl("~/App_Themes/Global/Site.css"), Version)%>' 
      type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I'm obtaining 
    <link type="text/css" />
as result, browser side, with your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string Version
    {
        get
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(asm.Location);
            return String.Format("{0}.{1}", fvi.ProductMajorPart, fvi.ProductMinorPart);
        }
    }
```